# How to change ReportServerUrl in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

We have 2 reporting server. One for test and one for production. Our business analyst will build the reports (rdl files) using Report Builder 3.0. After they complete the development and test on test reporting server (e.g. http://test/reportserver), we will modify the "ReportServerUrl" and Datasource, and then upload to production reporting server (e.g. http://prod/reportserver).

The problem is I cannot find in the Report Builder 3.0 UI how to configure this change. The only way I find is open the RDL file using Notepad, locate  and then change the URL.

Since our analyst are not programmers I want to avoid use notepad. May I know where is the button to change ReportServerUrl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you add a Shared DataSource to a report or edit an existing DataSource (and therefore connect to a Report Server), the current report server is updated. This is shown in the bottom left of your Report Builder window ("Current report server...") and also gets written to the `<rd:ReportServerUrl>` tag in the `.rdl` file itself. This is just an indicator of the last Report Server which was connected to by the report.

Therefore, if you wish to change the `<rd:ReportServerUrl>`, you just need to amend the DataSource(s) in the report to be ones which reside on the Report Server whose URL you wish to have appear.

Comment: I have a report which single datasource connectiontype =SQL server. I change to SQL server to production's SQL. Test connection is success. But when I save the report, close and open again, it still try to connect test reporting server.

Comment: Apologies, I assumed you were using shared DataSources. If I create a new blank report (and have no default Report Server set in Report Builder) and just add an embedded SQL Server DataSource and save the `.rdl`, no `<rd:ReportServerUrl>` value is added to the file. Are you saying that this is the process you have also followed, but you do end up with a `<rd:ReportServerUrl>` value in your `.rdl`?

Comment: I am not sure I have embedded SQL datasource or not. All I have is a single rdl file and play with it using Report Builder 3.0. The problem is whenever user double click the rdl on desktop, report builder open it and it is always connecting to http://test/reportserver. I want to show user how to change to http://prod/reportserver using report builder.

Comment: Within Report Builder, make sure you have the "Report Data" pane showing (this can be turned on through View -> Report Data) and expand the Data Sources folder. You will then see any Data Sources your report is using and can open each one by double clicking it (or right click -> Data Source Properties). Within the properties, you will see whether the Data Source is Shared or Embedded. I thought you were talking about an embedded data source as you mentioned that the "datasource connectiontype =SQL server".

Comment: Thanks for detail guide. I checked it is embedded source and the only source (SQL) is connecting to correct SQL server. But <rd:ReportServerUrl> node contain wrong server http://test/reportserver

Comment: Does that remain the case if you remove and re-add the Data Source?